# how to implement Connection pooling mechanism in server managed environment with Hibernate?

Tags: hibernate, tomcat, connection-pooling

As part of my web application i would like to implement Jdbc connection pooling mechanism in Apache Tomcat6 Web-Server managed environment with Hibernate. can any body suggest me how to implement it? I am using struts-hibernate with Tomcat6 server.

Any suggestions highly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Here's the page that comes as first result when you google for "tomcat 6 connection pool": http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-6.0-doc/jndi-datasource-examples-howto.html. It explains how to setup and configure a connection pool in tomcat 6, and how to access it from your application.

And here is the section of the Hibernate documentation that explains how to configure it to get connections from a JNDI data source of an app server like tomcat: http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/core/3.6/reference/en-US/html_single/#configuration-hibernatejdbc